# List number of posts in particular category filtered by author (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, archive, author

*EDIT: I elaborated more on this topic in another thread: [List categories by author ~ WITH COUNTER ~ (Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408347/list-categories-by-author-with-counter-wordpress/) ... it might be more suitable for you.*

When I'm in my Category page I want the readers to see who's posting there, and filter by Author. (Ex. Activism has 127 post, 37 by Adrian, 12 by James, etc…) I've tried a million things out there, but nothing serves my simple task! Anyone with similar experience out there?

This is what I've got:

```
<?php

$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

$auth_id = 1;
$cat_id = 2411;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM $wpdb->posts p
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
WHERE post_author = $auth_id
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND post_date <= NOW()
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = $cat_id
";
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
echo "This Author has published $post_count posts in Activism<br />";

?>
```

EDITED:

OK, this code works!!! ... I'm happy, but still a bit puzzled. Why does this work, and the pne above not?

```
<?php 

$auth_id = 1; 
$cat_id = 2411;

$counter = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $cat_id
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = '$auth_id'
";

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var($counter);


echo "Author... has $user_count posts in Activism<br />";

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to list the number of posts by an author in a **particular category**?

Comment: YES! That's what I'm trying to do...  I've got this code, but it's totally not doing the job:

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the first time I ask a Q here... usually I find what I'm looking for, but it's nice to contribute finally :P

Comment: Your query is working fine for me and showing the count then what problem you are facing

Comment: It always produces 0 as the result...