# List categories by author ~ WITH COUNTER ~ (Wordpress)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, taxonomy, author

This is the code that I've got. It gives a list of the categories a given author has published in. However, I would very much like to have a number next to the category name, telling how many posts the author has published in the different categories. Anyone knows a trick? Thanks!

```
<?php
$author = get_query_var('author');
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description
    FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
    WHERE 1=1 AND (
        posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
        posts.post_author = '$author' AND
        tax.taxonomy = 'category' )
    ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name.' '.$category->description; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

This code counts the posts in the category, and works fine. I want to combine this with the code above, but I don't know how to do it...

```
<?php
$counter = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 412
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = '1'
";


$user_count = $wpdb->get_var($counter);

echo $user_count;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL exists the `count()` function, which can count a number of rows. In your case, we want the number of posts, so we could use `COUNT(posts.id)`, like so :

```
<?php
$author = get_query_var('author');
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description, count(posts.id) AS `count`
    FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
    WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
        posts.post_author = '$author' AND
        tax.taxonomy = 'category'
    ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name.'('.$category->count.') '.$category->description; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You'll note that I used and alias to rename the count column (otherwise, its name would have been `count(posts.id)` - not really practical).
I have also removed the `1=1` in the WHERE because it is not useful here.

Comment: Close, but still not quite there. Your code only produced one line (one category) and the counter seems to be for all the posts in that category, and not only the ones written by that specific author :(

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out... had to run to separate SELECT functions: one to fetch the list of categories, and then one more functions within that loop to count how many entries there is within the category. I would have preferred to have these two loops as one, but this works out for me.

```
<?php

// This will get us a list of the categories that our Author has published in
$author = get_query_var('author');
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("

SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description
FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
    posts.post_author = '$author' AND
    tax.taxonomy = 'category' 
ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");


// This loop picks up categories
foreach($categories as $category) : 

$catid = $category->ID;

// Now, inside the loop, we need to count how many posts that the Author has published.
$counter = "SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $catid
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = '$author'
";

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var($counter);

echo '<div class="archive_author">' . $category->name . '<br/><span class="subcounter">' . $user_count . ' posts</span></div>';

endforeach; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this plugin ( http://wordpress.org/plugins/author-profiles/ ) to display in the sidebar. 
And I guess this code will help any one

```
  <?php

  global $wpdb;
  $table_users.=$wpdb->base_prefix;
  $table_users.="users";
  $table_posts.=$wpdb->base_prefix;
  $table_posts.="posts";


  $fetch_authordata="SELECT count(p.post_author) as post1,c.id, c.user_login, c.display_name,c.user_nicename, c.user_email, c.user_url, c.user_registered FROM {$table_users} as c , {$table_posts} as p {$where} and p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' and c.id=p.post_author GROUP BY p.post_author order by post1 DESC limit {$author_numbers}  ";

  $dispaly_authordata = (array) $wpdb->get_results("{$fetch_authordata}", object);


  foreach ( $dispaly_authordata as $author ) {
  $user = get_userdata($author->id);

  echo 'Display Name: '.$user->display_name;
  echo 'Post Count: '.$post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);

  }
 ?>
```