# Count posts of child category in parent category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories, hierarchy

Hallo Wordpress Community,

I need your help.

I have a Woocommerce shop site with multiple authors. In the sidebar I want to display a list of woocommerce product categories by author (based on posts which an author made), accompanied by a product post counter. I use following code by [2famousTV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539097/2famous-tv), which works fine to get the categories by author and a counter. I modified it so it only shows parent categories.

---

```
<?php

global $post, $wpdb;

// This will get us a list of the categories that our Author has published in
$author = get_query_var('author');
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("

SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description
FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
posts.post_author = '$author' AND
tax.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");


// This loop picks up categories
foreach($categories as $category) : 

$catid = $category->ID;

// Now, inside the loop, we need to count how many posts that the Author has published.
$counter = "SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID =     $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $catid
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'

// modification  

AND tax.parent = '0'

// modification end

AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = '$author'
";

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var($counter);

echo '<div class="archive_author">' . $category->name . '<br/><span    class="subcounter">' . $user_count . ' posts</span></div>';

endforeach; 

?>
```

Source: [Link to original post by 2famous-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422040)

---

My question:

With this code the parent category counter only counts items within the parent category but not the items within its child categories. How can I make the parent category counter include the posts of the child category without actually assigning the posts to the parent category?

```
Category_______________Counter_____________Posts

Parent-Category___________0__________________0

-Child-Category A_________2__________________2

-Child-Category B_________3__________________3
```

*should be:*

```
Category________________Counter____________Posts

Parent-Category___________5__________________0

-Child-Category A_________2__________________2

-Child-Category B_________3__________________3
```

---

I tried it with several Wordpress inherid options like "wp_list_categories", "get_terms" and "get_the_term" but did not bring results. It seems the only way to go through Mysql. I am not firm enough to make that happen. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is NOT a function. Beyond that, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry.
I actually don't know how to provide you with a DDL or an sqlfiddle. Whould it help if I send you a link to a test site?

Comment: Not really. I'd only really be interested in the SQL side of the problem - the data set and the desired result set. If I was you I'd figure out how sqlfiddle works.

Comment: Ok. I let you know when i figured out how to use sqlfiddle. Thanks for the quick response.